# UnboundLocalError while submitting radio button form in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, radio-button

I am new to Django and I am working on a site which should take user input from Radio Button and use the selected value for further operations. I have seen some ways using Database, but I want to use a simple way to directly get the value of the selected radio button from the template.

I am using Django forms and I am getting **UnboundLocalError** when submitting the form in HTML. It shows that *local variable 'selected' referenced before assignment*. I understand that the form is not valid, but I do not know why kindly help me out.

PFA my codes.

views.py (Only the part where value of selected radio button is accessed)

```
def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        form = CHOICES(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
           selected = form.cleaned_data.get("NUMS")

        else:
           form = CHOICES()


        
        worksheet = wb["Observed"]
        worksheet1 = wb[selected]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

NUMS= [
    ('one', 'one'),
    ('two', 'two'),
    ('three', 'three'),
    ('four', 'four'),
    ('five', 'five')

    ]
class CHOICES(forms.Form):
    NUMS = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=NUMS)
```

index.html (Only the part of Radio buttons)

```
<form action="index" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.NUMS}}
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="NUMS" name="NUMS" value="1 Day Lead">
                    <label for="NUMS">1 Day Lead</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="NUMS" name="NUMS" value="2 Day Lead">
                    <label for="NUMS">2 Days Lead</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="NUMS" name="NUMS" value="3 Day Lead" checked>
                    <label for="NUMS">3 Days Lead</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="NUMS" name="NUMS" value="4 Day Lead">
                    <label for="NUMS">4 Days Lead</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="NUMS" name="NUMS" value="5 Day Lead">
                    <label for="NUMS">5 Days Lead</label>
                    
                    
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your form data is invalid, so the `selected` variable is never defined. However you attempt to return it a few lines below. You can perhaps fix this by adding a default for `selected` so it will always exist:

```
selected = None 
if form.is_valid():
   selected = form.cleaned_data.get("NUMS")
else:
   form = CHOICES()

worksheet = wb["Observed"]
worksheet1 = wb[selected]
```

Comment: It is raising a KeyError.

Comment: https://dpaste.com/CXD4FW8LL

PFA full error traceback

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. You're trying to assign a variable to a dictionary key of None in wb, which will fail. If your business logic here requires that your serializer is valid, you should put your logic under a block where you're sure that's the case and perhaps gracefully exist if the serializer is not valid.

Comment: Hey Rob, I am new to Django and did not exactly understand your answer. 
Specifying where and what changes I should make in my code will help.